# Get products collection by store id in magento2

Tags: magento2, product-collection, magento2.3.3

How get product collection by store id 
I tried below code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');   
 $proCollection = $productCollection->create()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addStoreFilter(3)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('brand', $brand)
                ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', 4);
```

but I'm not getting the products

Comment: try with this $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

Comment: I tried but not working

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
$collection->addStoreFilter($storeid)
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_code');
```

You can use "addStoreFilter()" Method of class "\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory".

Note:- Here I used object manager for just reference but you avoid to use object manager.

**Update 1** (without object manager, use Magento construct dependancy)

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;

protected $collectionFactory

public function __construct(CollectionFactory $collectionFactory)
{ 
   $this->collectionFactory =$collectionFactory; 
}

public function productCollection()
{ 
   $storeId = 2; //
   $collection = $collectionFactory->create();
   $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
   $collection->addStoreFilter($storeId) 
   $collection->addAttributeToFilter('ATTRIBUTE CODE'); 
   return $collection;
}
```

Comment: it is not working

Comment: r u using product resource model or model?

Comment: Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory 
this one I'm using

Answer (score 1):

> You can run  below script in magento root and get Products By Store Id

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
 $proCollection = $productCollection->create()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addStoreFilter(1)
                ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', 4);
echo count($proCollection);
?>
```